# How to allow users to delete their account in frontend

Tags: account

I am developing account page. And almost done except Deleting user Account. I want users to delete their account in frontend.

This is my code of the account-delete.php. but it doesn't work. I don't know why.

```
 add_action( 'init', 'rnm_remove_user_account' );
```

Maybe, this is doesn't work.  Can you help me?

```
<?php
/* Recheck if user is logged in just to be sure, this should have been done already */
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}

//delete user. Maybe this part makes errors. 
if ( is_user_logged_in() && $_GET['myaccount'] == 'delete'  ) {

    add_action( 'init', 'rnm_remove_user_account' );
}

function rnm_remove_user_account() {
    // Verify that the user intended to take this action.


    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    wp_delete_user( $current_user->ID );

    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}




if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();



    //탈퇴 내용 체크 확인
    $pass1 = $_POST['deletecheck'];
    if( empty($_POST['deletecheck']) ){
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?validation=deletchecknone' );
        exit;
    } else if( $_POST['deletecheck'] == 'yes' ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?myaccount=delete' );
        exit;
    } else {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?validation=unknown' );
        exit;
    }



    /* We got here, assuming everything went OK */
    wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?updated=true' );
    exit;

}
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="rnm_page">

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


        <?php if( !empty( $_GET['validation'] ) ): ?>

            <?php if( $_GET['validation'] == 'deletchecknone' ): ?>
                <div class="error"><?php _e('<p class="rnm_login_msg">!! Please check to delete your account.</p>', 'mythmeme'); ?></div>
            <?php elseif( $_GET['validation'] == 'unknown' ): ?>
                <div class="error"><?php _e('<p class="rnm_login_msg">!! Unknown Error!</p>', 'mythmeme'); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

        <form method="post" id="rnm_account_form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <p class="form-password">
                <label for="deletecheck"><?php _e('Delete My Account', 'mythmeme'); ?> </label>
                <input name="deletecheck" type="checkbox" id="deletecheck" class="checkbox" value="yes"  />
            </p>


            <p class="form-submit">
                <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="rnm_wp_submit" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Delete My Account', 'mythmeme'); ?>" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user3' ); ?>
                <input name="honey-name" value="" type="text" style="display:none;"></input>
                <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
            </p><!-- .form-submit -->

        </form><!-- #rnm_account_form -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


</div>




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: In what way doesn’t it work?

Comment: I edited more detail. please read once more...

Comment: Where is this file? How is it called?

Comment: This is page. And I added this code in page-account-delete.php.

Comment: Ah. Your init action won’t fire because it is added too late in the WordPress code run. If you move the add_action and it’s function to your functions.php then they will be defined before the init hook fires. Also you don’t want an HTML space before your get_header call, so remove that too, or PHP may complain about headers already being sent.

Comment: Thanks your comment. I moved those add_action and it's function to my functions.php. But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using something like this ? : https://www.engagewp.com/wordpress-allow-users-delete-accounts/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I solved the problem. I don't use any hook to  delete the account . Instead, I use above function directly. It works.